# Including DB2 Environment with WPF Build

Tags: c#, wpf, db2

I've been building a WPF program which makes a query to a DB2 database. During testing I ran into no problems but when I migrated a build of the program to another computer it would crash. I was able to debug using VS and got this error:

> The ‘IBMDADB2’ provider is not registered on the local machine

According to an article (http://myblog4fun.com/archive/2012/06/23/the-ibmdadb2-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine.aspx) this error occurs because the DB2 environment is not setup on the computer.

The process is a pain and was wondering is there a way to include the DB2 environment with my program? Are there any alternatives to this? I'm a beginner to WPF and C# forms so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The majority of the article you linked just describes how to find the download for the DB2 .NET provider. Really, this is something you only need to do once. Once you have the installer downloaded you can manually install it when you deploy the application, or build it into an installer.

If you don't want to use an installer, you could execute the exe containing the DB2 provider manually from code:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Process.Start("C:\\pathToExe");
    }
}
```

You may want to check out [Deploying a WPF Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969776%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to find a deployment option that will work for you.